# raku Calling same function in threads with different parameters

Tags: multithreading, function, parameters, raku

I remember back in college days, threads share resources and memory. I do not know the specifics of Raku implementation of threads, but if, at the same time, multiple threads call the same global function with different parameters, will they interfere one another because a global function is a single block of code shared by all the threads? E.g., this example does not show interference, but what about some complicated codes?

```
sub add ($a, $b) { $a + $b };
for 1..100 { start { sleep 1.rand; say "I am $_, {add($_, 1000)}"; } };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not have to worry about accessing a global function from multiple threads at the same time, in principle: arguments are passed by value, and parameters are lexical to the function.

There is *one* exception I can think of: using a `state` variable inside such a function.  There is a known race-condition on the initialization of a state variable, and updates of the form `$foo++` will most likely miss increments when being run from multiple threads at the same time.  E.g.:

```
my int $a;
await (^10).map: { start { $a++ for ^100000 } }
say $a;  # 893127
```

Aka, not the `1000000` you'd expect.  Fortunately, to handle that case, we have atomic integers:

```
my atomicint $a;
await (^10).map: { start { $a⚛++ for ^100000 } }
say $a;  # 1000000
```

But that's just showing off and not directly an answer to your question :-)

Should you have a piece of code that you want to make sure that only one thread executes at a time, you could use a `Lock` and the `protect` method on that;

```
my $lock = Lock.new;  # usually in the mainline of a program
# ... code
$lock.protect: {
    # code executed by only 1 thread at a time
}
```

Please note that this is considered to be "plumbing", aka use this only when you need to, as it opens you up to deadlocks.

Comment: Module `OO:Monitors` can also help guarantee that only one thread at a time runs a method from an object.

Comment: Great information ! Thank you very much Elizabeth Mattijsen !!! And thank you  Curt Tilmes for pointing out 00:Monitors !